# How to escape a string "%s" on Android shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I send strings from my PC to Android app, and the app executes a shell command to enter a text:

```
input text "text"
```

I do escape all the special characters. For space, I replace it with "%s" and the problem is that I cannot enter a string "%s" itself. Android shell interprets it as a whitespace.

My attempts and problems:

1. **Splitting a text**. If there are "%s" strings in the text, I split the whole text into words (e.g. `words[n]`), so that the words end with "%" and starts from "s". For example, if the text is "qwe%s34g" (let's say its a password), I split it as `words[n] = { "qwe%", "s34g" }`. Then I run the `input text` command `n` times. 

   **Problem:** This is not smooth. Each `input text` command takes considerable time and I don't like a time gap after each word is input.
2. **Using `input keyevent` command**. I just replace each letter with its respective keycode and use `input keyevent Keycode_strings`. 

   **Problem:** Not all of the characters have their keycode, such as, '!', '?',  etc.

I want to enter it with one command execution, so it would be smooth. And I want to enter a string "%s". Could you suggest me any solutions?

---

**Edit**:

I am using [UiDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice)** class for command execution on android app:

```
...
if (!text.isEmpty()) {
    getUiDevice().executeShellCommand("input text " + text);
}
...
```

** *UiDevice*: UiDevice provides access to state information about the device. You can also use this class to simulate user actions on the device, such as pressing the d-pad or pressing the Home and Menu buttons.

Comment: What is string which you want to enter?

Comment: I can enter any strings. The problem arises when a string contains the "%s", ex. "qwert%sqert", "1992qw %s 430". All the "%s" are interpreted as whitespace.

Comment: I don't thing %s can be escaped. I would like to see answer of this question.